Isaiah claims he saw the Lord Jesus Christ sitting on a throne at Isaiah 6:1-5. What is the response from the Jehovah's Witnesses?

In the year of King Uzzah's death, I saw the Lord sitting on a throne, lofty and exalted with the train of His robe filling the temple. Vs2, Seraphim stood above Him and at vs3 one called out to another and said, "Holy, Holy, Holy, is the Lord of hosts, The whole earth is full of His glory.
Vs5, "Then I said, "Woe is me, for I am ruined! Because I am a man of unclean lips, For my eyes have seen the King, the Lord of hosts."

The verb Isaiah used for "saw" in Isaiah 6:1 is (ra'ah). it refers to the act of seeing in the literal sense, to see with the eyes (as opposed to, for example, "machazeh", which is the act or event of an ecstatic "vision)"
This event is backed up by the Apostle John at John 12:41. "These things Isaiah said, because he saw His glory, and he spoke of Him." John, in referring to this event uses the Greek word (eidon)--also a verb referring to the act of seeing with the eyes in the natural sense.

@Kris 136 'Adonay ad-o-noy' am emphatic form of 113; the Lord (used as a proper name of God only):--(my) Lord. This is from Stong's Lexicon on Hebrew words. Look it up yourself.

There are many different Christological views that would fit under the broad category of "denies the deity of Christ". And the body of this question just looks like an argument you're making, not an actual question.

@curiousdannii  I edited the question and the body. Is it alright now?

Yes, that's a lot better, thanks.

@Kris Your right, it is Jehovah sitting on a throne that Isaiah sees and the Apostle John makes this clear at John 12:41. It was the glory of Jesus Christ that John identifies. At Isaiah 6, the prophet saw God sitting upon a throne. In chapter 53 Isaiah viewed Christ upon the Cross. Isaiah and John connect these two as one and the same being. It was difficult for the Jews to associate their Messiah with suffering and death. Isaiah at 8:14 describes the Lord as a rock of offense and a stone of stumbling to all of Israel. Can't you see the connection Kriss?

@Kris. It's not necessary for "snide" remarks. The definition of "vision." The faculty or state of being able to see. eyesight, sight. I even gave you Hebrew word used for seeing with the physical eyes and I gave you the Greek word for "vision" in which both words refer to seeing with the eyes. Go ahead, I welcome more objections.

It looks like you've already asked this question a few years ago: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86545/for-those-who-deny-the-deity-of-jesus-christ-how-do-you-explain-isaiah-seeing-ch

@Mr.Bond Regarding your assertion that a vision is real and observed physically I direct you to the experience of Peter in Acts 12:9.   Peter had experience with visions from God and indicates they were not real as opposed to the angel coming to him in prison and effecting his escape.

@Kris Look at the context starting at Acts 12:7. The angel physically appears to Peter and struck Peter's side and told him to get up. And his chains fell off of his hands. This a real time event, not a vision. Peter in his mind thought it was a vision but it was not. He was surprised at what was happening. Instead of coming up with text that YOU THINK disputes Isaiah 6 and especially at John 12:41 why don't you try and deal with them? Jesus has to be the subject and not God the Father. vs41, and he spoke of Him. Who's the Him? Vs42, Nevertheless many even of the rulers believed IN Him, WHO?

Peter was at first not sure if it was real or a vision. Why would the Bible tell us this? The Meaning is a vision is not real. But what Peter experienced with the angel breaking him out of jail was real.,,,btw Thats how Isaiah can see Jehovah and not die. Vision= not real

@Kris What do you mean that vision is not real? A vision is an encounter with God where he imparts special revelation to a person. So, if as you say Isaiah had a vision it's still real where God imparted information. The Apostle John under the influence of the Holy Spirit clearly claimed that the vision was about Jesus Christ sitting on the throne and identified as the Lord of hosts. John 12:41-42. You did get one thing right when you said it was Jehovah, this means that Jesus Christ is Jehovah. And btw, of course God cannot die but as a man He can die only in the physical sense. Acts 20:28.

@Mr.Bond read more carefully.   I said “  Thats how Isaiah can see Jehovah and not die.” If the appearance of Jehovah was real like the angel that came to Peter Isaiah would have perished.

@Kris Well if that's true then explain Genesis 16:13 where Hagar says, "Thou are a God who sees; for she said, "Have I even remained alive after seeing Him?" And what about Jacob at Genesis 32:30, "I have seen God face to face and yet my life has been spared." God also physically appeared to Jacob at Genesis 35:7-16 as well. At Judges 13:1-23 the parents of Samson saw God. Abraham saw God at Genesis 17:1-3 and at Genesis 18:1-5. They all lived to tell about it.

@Mr.Bond ok got it! God is a liar!

@Kris By making that "rhetorical" statement which means of course God cannot lie implies that the people I mentioned, Hagar, Jacob, Abraham and Manora, and others I can name, their the liars. The truth is that nobody is lying. The problem is with you because you do not know how to "reconcile" scriptures that "seem" to contradict each other. In my thread I quoted Isaiah and I also quoted the Apostle John.  Which one of these two is lying? Here's your options. They are both wrong. One of them is right and the other is wrong. Or they are both right.  Which option do you choose Kris?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You state:“The verb Isaiah used for "saw" in Isaiah 6:1 is (ra'ah). it refers to the act of seeing in the literal sense”.        The word ra’ah  is used to tell about what a person dreamed in a dream.  See Pharoah telling Joseph about the fat cows and skinny cows.  Genesis 41:17-31

Te Isaiah 6:1. Some 105 Hebrew manuscripts read Jehovah at this verse Isa 6:1 instead of Adonaiʹ. ... This is one of the 134 places where the Hebrew Sopherim changed the name Jehovah in the primitive text to read Adonaiʹ, My Lord, lest Isaiah should be said to have seen Jehovah God.

@Kris I agree that some 105 Hebrews manuscripts read Jehovah at Isaiah 6:1. Your missing John's point at John 12:37-42. Vs37 Jesus performs many signs and they were believing Him; vs38, that the word of Isaiah might be fulfilled, which he spoke. John is referencing Isaiah 53:1 referring to the Lord/God. Vs39-40 God blinds them. The key verse is41, "These things Isaiah said, because he saw His glory, and he spoke of Him. John is clearly referring to Jesus Christ and confirms it at vs42 when John says, "Nevertheless many even of the rulers believed  in Him. Again, the Him is Jesus Christ.

Cont. Jesus Christ is Jehovah God according to John. Are you aware that the name "Jehovah" is the Anglicized version of the Hebrew "YHWH," which is the verb to BE. It translated as "I AM" or as "I will Be" according to every Hebrew lexicon. Why am I saying this? Because at John 8:58 Jesus says, "Truly, truly I say to you, before Abraham was born, "I am." At vs56 Jesus says, "Your father Abraham rejoiced to see My day, and he saw it and was glad." I believe from Genesis 17:1-2 that Abraham realized what had been promised to him via the covenant the pre-incarnate Son made with him was fulfilled.

The first Biblical proof that suggests Jesus and God are two separate entities is the verse in the Book of Genesis where God says these words
Genesis 1:26-28

Then God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness

The phrase us implies more than one entity and the other entity must have been listening to God at this point because God cannot talk to himself.
The other second proof that suggests two separate entities is during his trials in the wilderness when he was tempted, the devil challenges his sonship to God by stating that God will send his angels to grab Jesus lest he strikes his foot against a stone.
Luke 4:10

And he took him to Jerusalem and set him on the pinnacle of the temple and said to him, “If you are the Son of God, throw yourself down from here, for it is written, “‘He will command his angels concerning you, to guard you,’ and “‘On their hands they will bear you up, lest you strike your foot against a stone.’”

The verse above is one of the most remarkable verses in the entire Bible because

It reveals to us that the devil knows the truth and knows all scripture
Despite knowing the truth, the devil still chooses to challenge it and attack it

The truth according to the devil is that God who is the Father will command his angels to save Jesus but Jesus was sure God would do that so why put Him to the test?
All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Jesus, that authority was with someone else before it was passed to Jesus because he had a duty to fulfill and a very difficult task to beat, save mankind from the power of sin. Jesus confesses that he has received this power which he didn't have before he completed the works of salvation
Mathew 28:18

All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me

Jesus didn't have this authority until it was given to him after he beat the devil and the world on the cross.
We both know that Jesus existed before Adam and Eve were created and this is evident when Jesus himself said these words.

I beheld Satan fall from heaven like lightning

Jesus was there when the rebellion happened but he wasn't given the authority until this moment of triump when he broke through the curse of death and sin through his righteousness.
The Image of God expressed through a man and a woman
It's because the image of God is Jesus sitting at the right hand of God like a woman sitting at the right hand of a man, this image doesn't make a woman a man and neither does it make Jesus God, Jesus would never take a scroll from himself. God gives Jesus the scrolls to open because they are two different distinct entities.
The lamb is worthy to open the scrolls because he is distinct and unique from the One sitter on the Great White Throne who hands it out.
What Isaiah saw is a vision of the GWT, who is the Lord that tells the other Lord who is Jesus to sit at his right hand till he makes his enemies his footstool according to the Psalmist. There are two lords in heaven just as man and woman are lords over all of creation.
Psalms 110:1

The LORD said to my Lord, “Sit in the place of honor at my right hand until I humble your enemies, making them a footstool under your feet.”

Seek the truth with diligence and you shall always find it

You have not addressed the question? Isaiah 6:1, "In the year of King Uzzah's death, I saw the Lord sitting on a throne." At vs5, "For my eyes have seen the King, the Lord of hosts." The Apostle John at 12:41 states, "These things Isaiah said, because (or why?) he/Isaiah saw His glory/who's glory, AND HE SPOKE OF HIM." So again, who is the "Him" is Isaiah referring to at Isaiah 6:1? To make matters even worse for you, look at John 12:42, (the next vs) "Nevertheless, (which means in spite of the above facts/vs41, many even of the rulers believed in Him," The "Him" Isaiah saw was Jesus Christ.

@Mr.Bond, What Isaiah saw is a vision of the GWT, who is the lord that tells the other lord who is Jesus to sit at his right hand till he makes his enemies his footstool. There are two lords in heaven just as man and woman are lords over all of creation

No he didn't! The verb Isaiah used for "saw" in Isaiah 6:1 is (ra'ah). it refers to the act of seeing in the literal sense, to see with the eyes (as opposed to, for example, "machazeh", which is the act or event of an ecstatic "vision)" The Apostle John used the Greek word "eidon," also a verb referring to the act of seeing with the eyes in the natural sense. Now, you still have not answered my question from John 12:41? Who is the Him at vs41? Also vs42, Nevertheless many even of the rulers believed IN  HIM," Who's the Him? Btw, 1 Corinthians 8:6, "and one Lord, Jesus Christ." Not two Lords.

@Mr.Bond wrong

@Mr.Bond when you describe a dream you would use the word saw.  That doesn’t make your dream a reality.

I dreamed Mr Bond came to my Door . I saw him in my security camera. Mr bond was dressed in a blue three piece suit that had bright pink spots on the lapels. His hat was like a sombrero but the top had a propeller spinning at the speed of a helicopter in full lift mode.    The fact that I use the word “saw”means this really happened.

@Kris, No, I am not wrong and I can prove it. Genesis 15:1, After these things the word of the Lord came to Abraham IN A VISION, saying, Do not fear, Abrah, I am a shield to you; Your reward shall be very great." Vs2, And Abram said, "O Lord God, what will Thou give me, since I am childless etc. Now, read verses 3-9 and you tell me the if the words of the Lord God in this vision came true? Let's say Isaiah 6:1 is a vision (and it's not) explain why the Apostle John at John 12:41 and 42 why his words were the truth that it was Jesus Christ Isaiah saw?

@Mr.Bond Isaiah 1:1

@Kris Are you for real! Are you telling me that hat Peter went through by being in the jail at Acts and what Isaiah saw was not real? Your so brainwashed by the Jehovah's Witnesses organization that you can't tell the difference between what is real and what is false? Like someone told me decades ago, please give me your exegesis or explanation of the verses in a way that they don't say what they mean?

@Kris. Isaiah 2:1, "The word which Isaiah the son of Amoz "SAW" concerning Judah and Jerusalem."

@Mr.Bond have I ever declared you to be brainwashed by the Calvary Baptist movement?

@Kris  No, and I sincerely apologize for the comment.
